# set values based on scatter plot visualization python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scatter-plot, scatter

Is it possible to set labels to variables if it's located in some section in a scatter plot? or only manually?

Each colourful dot is variable.

[that's what I get with help of a scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRDEQ.png)

As a result I'd like to get this with some python script, but I couldn't find out how:

```
var   | label
-------------
3 65  | low
3 40  | low
7 180 | high
     ...
5 40  | undervalued
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any matplotlib function that does what you want, but you can annotate your points easily with `annotate`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# So starting from your example
y = [65, 40, 180, 40]
x = [3, 3, 7, 5]
labels = ['low', 'low', 'high', 'undervalued']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)

for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(label, (x[i], y[i]))
```

Or if you have some intervals for each label, you can write up a function that gives back the desired label, like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Based on the image you provided
def get_label(x,y):
    if x<4 and y<100:
        return 'low'
    elif x<4 and y>=100:
        return 'overvalued'
    elif x>=4 and y<100:
        return 'undervalued'
    else:
        return 'high'

y = [65, 40, 180, 40]
x = [3, 3, 7, 5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)

for x_current, y_current in zip(x,y):
    ax.annotate(get_label(x_current, y_current), (x_current, y_current))
```

You can find more formatting in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).